# How to open a modal on a new page

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

I need to know how to link from one page to another page. On second page I need to show a specific modal. Best Case is to show some specific category in the modal.
Actually, the homepage link is `dev.prdruck.com`. From this page I want to link to a design gallery which is found under http://dev.prdruck.com/shirt-designer/?product_id=190&color=FFFFFF
From this page, I can open the "Design Gallery" unter the button "Motive hinzufügen" which had the id `#dg-cliparts`. 
I tested the following but nothing happens...

I add the following at the end of the shirt-designer page:

$(document).ready(function() { var modals = [’#dg-cliparts’]; if (window.location.hash && ~modals.indexOf(window.location.hash)) { $(window.location.hash).modal(); } })

But if i link to http://dev.prdruck.com/shirt-designer/#dg-cliparts nothing happens.

Maybe somebody had an idea?
Thank you
Junes

Comment: Open the modal with JavaScript on page load?

Comment: The goal doesn't make sense. _Modal_ is meant to be a pop-up, which more or less halts the execution on a page it was called until user closes the pop-up.

Comment: Sure, i want to show the designs and don´t need a new page for this. I want to link from the homepage or from a button or anything else to the open design gallery.

Answer (score 0):

As you said it should work for you. Here when we click button new window with the ID of the modal will be open and the browser will get the `#` from the URL and will open the modal when window is loaded...!

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.btn').on('click', function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        window.open(urlHere + '#myModal', '');
    });
    $(window).load(function () {
        $(window.location.hash).modal("show");
    });
});
```

Here `urlHere` is the url of the page on which you want to open the modal and `myModal` is the ID of the modal.

Comment: I add the following to the shirt-designer page via visual composer - Javascript feature, but nothing happens:

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.btn').on('click', function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        window.open(http://dev.prdruck.com/shirt-designer/?product_id=190&color=FFFFFF + '#dg-cliparts', '');
    });
    $(window).load(function () {
        $(window.location.hash).modal("show");
    });
});
</script>

Comment: Your button is on same page in which you added this code..?

Comment: You need to paste the button click code on the page where you have button  and paste the code of window load where you want to open the modal.

Comment: i do it exactly like you say, but no success. Maybe a problem, because the shirt designer load from another subfolder. Here a link to a screenshot. http://imgur.com/a/tuPs0

Comment: here you will get the same thing. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45008678/open-bootstrap-modal-in-new-tab/45011982#45011982