# need a solution to redirect to another page and aslo has to open a modal in that page

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I need a special requirement. I have a page named as index.html(which is home page) in which there is a modal called "login", I kept it hidden by default(display="none"). I have another page named as signup.html in which I have signup related code, in that code I have a line "already have an account? **LOGIN**". Now, my requirement is if user clicks that **LOGIN** in signup.html page, index.html page [image: the image is when login modal is not hidden in index.html. I want like that when user clicks "LOGIN" in signup.html page]has to open along with login modal

Comment: This link may help you:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45008678/open-bootstrap-modal-in-new-tab

Answer (score 0):

url would be something like abc.com/about#modal-id

you just need to add your model-id in url link.

Thanks.

Comment: thanks for your reply. Here problem is, according to your exam "modal-id" is hidden by default(display='none').

Comment: can you share a snippet of code ? for better understanding.